IP Assignment for applying ACL on Cisco Nexus3500 C3548P-10GX Chassis
Context
Following are the details of the layer-3 switch
cisco Nexus3500 C3548P-10GX Chassis
Intel(R) Core(TM) i3- CPU @ 2.50GHz with 16396528 kB of memory.
Processor Board ID FOC25244X6C

We have created ACL to filter/reject UDP packets
IP access list mylist
10 deny udp any any
20 permit tcp any any

Now we wish to apply this ACL on Interface.
However, the interfaces of the Switch are configured as switchport.
In order to apply ACL, we need to configure the Switch Interface as a routed port

Question
The real question is of IP Assignment.
What IP should I assign to switch interfaces Eth1/1 and Eth1/2 so that connectivity isn't compromised when we do no switchport?
The Servers which are connected by switch have been assigned IP as xxx.xxx.201.160 and xxx.xxx.201.105. Both have subnet as 255.255.255.0.
For them to stay connected, the first three octets (xxx.xxx.201) should be same.
However, while assigning IP to switch ports, the error prompts that first three octets cannot be same for Eth1/1 and Eth1/2.
What IP then should we assign to ports so that connectivity isn't compromised?

The ACL goes on the gateway interface with the gateway IP address.

Yeah, this does not go on a layer 2 switch. You need to peform protocol level traffic controls on the IP gateway device, not the layer 2 switching platform.

It is a Layer 3 Switch, @FrameHowitzer.

The ACL is to restrict traffic between networks, so you place it on the gateway interface for the network. An ACL will restrict traffic in and out of a network. If you want to restrict traffic at the server level, then place the restrictions on the server firewall.

On the Nexus 3K series you can bind an ACL to a switched port, an L3 routed port or a VLAN - so there's no need to go for routed ports. See https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus3548/sw/security/6-x/b_N3548_Security_Config_602_A11/b_N3548_Security_Config_602_A11_chapter_0111.html

What IP should I assign to switch interfaces Eth1/1 and Eth1/2 so that connectivity isn't compromised when we do no switchport?

When you configure a routed port, each port needs to use an IP address from the subnet it is connected to.
However, the way you are asking seems to indicate that you really want L2 connectivity between those ports and keep them switched. Using routed ports means there are different subnets on the switch's interfaces and you route between them - connected hosts need to use the switch as a gateway to the other subnet.
